# How to select the scroll bar rendered by Javascript in Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, angular, selenium

I am using Selenium to extract information from a company private site. I have used Selenium before, I know how to select elements, enter keys, scroll and so on. However this is the first time that I have encountered a **scroll bar that is actually rendered by Javascript that is not part of the original HTML**. The information is rendered by interactive scripts which is angular JS I believe.

I have no idea how to select this. I have located the element in the picture. I tried `browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,300)")` and similar scroll to element but it does not work. I believe because the original window does not have a scroll bar that is why it will fail. However

```
test = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '''/html/body/ess-root/core-ui-theme/ess-core-layout/pol-layout/pol-content/ess-employee-list-page/
div/div/ess-employee-cards-container/cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport''')
browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,300)', test)
```

This does not work either. I am kind of out of ideas on what to do. Do I need to try to select this using pixels?

[image: Element that contains the scroll bar]

The website layout looks like this.

[image: Website structure]

The expanded contents inside the element:
[image]

Update: I played around with the element attribute. It does work somewhat. It can scrolls up and down, however, the table content is not updated, so now my screen is blank. This code modifies style of the element, but I suspect something else is still missing.

```
test2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '''/html/body/ess-root/core-ui-theme/ess-core-layout/pol-layout/pol-content/
ess-employee-list-page/div/div/ess-employee-cards-container/cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport/div[1]''')
password = browser.execute_script('arguments[0].style = style="transform: translateY(-356px);"', test2)
```

Update 2: I solved the problem by using `pyautogui`. I have to manually direct the mouse to move to the scroll bar and let it scroll down (because scrolling only works if the mouse is in focus of the table). I got all the information that I wanted. However, I still prefer a pure selenium approach if possible.

Comment: Can you share the site link, if possible?

Comment: I am sorry I cannot share the site. I can give you the site without the credentials https://ess.hrmos.co/login

Comment: You like to reach an element or want to act on scrollbar?

Comment: Do in your browser -> ctrl_shift+I -> Click on Element Tab -> press Ctrl+F -> And now test your xpath there. In short open developer tool and check your xpath, is it correct or not? Give this one a try: //*[contains(@class,'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport')] . Your xpath or locator should always return 1 item until specifically it is used for getting multiple items.

Comment: I just want to scroll the bar so it will show more elements

Comment: Can you check with this? browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(2000,0)")

Comment: I tried scrollBy, it did not work. With regarding to the previous xpath test. It select the whole thing (What I mean is, it contains the whole table and with the scroll bar I believe)